# how to calculate the angle between the mid of a clicked donut element and the negative y-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flot

[image]Consider the following code[sample donut chart using jquery-flot](http://jsfiddle.net/c5zsg6y3/26/) , now as i have added the 'image' class on click of the donut, i want to dynamically add the degree in the 'image' class so that the clicked item will be facing down at the bottom ( like on the -ve side of the y-axis ).`

```
var data = [{
    label: "Pause",
    data: 150
}, {
    label: "No Pause",
    data: 100
}, {
    label: "yes Pause",
    data: 80
}, {
    label: "Sleeping",
    data: 250
}];

var options = {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true,
            innerRadius: 0.5,
            radius: 1,
            startAngle: 1,

        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true
    },
    legend: {
    show: false
    },
    stroke: {
    width: 4
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        cssClass: "flotTip",
        content: "%s: %p.0%",
        defaultTheme: false
    }
};
$("#pie-placeholder").bind("plotclick", function(event, pos, obj) {
   $("#pie-placeholder").addClass('image')

    });
var plot = $.plot($("#pie-placeholder"), data, options);
```

`

Note:- this is done using Jquery flot

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: Hey @Chris, its simple..just look at the donut on the link,what  i wanted to achieve is whenever user clicks on the donut item, donut should spin and the selected item should at the bottom poisition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0vw74j66/) you can find my solution to your problem if I got you right.

```
$("#pie-placeholder").bind("plotclick", function(event, pos, obj) {
if (obj) {
    var percentInRads = 0.02;
    var currSegmentInRads = percentInRads * obj.datapoint[0]
    var currSegmentOffset = currSegmentInRads / 2;
    var currSegmentStart = currSegmentOffset >= 0.5 ? -0.5 + currSegmentOffset : 0.5 - currSegmentOffset;
    var total = 0;
    var beforeTotal = 0;

    for (var idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
      var segment = data[idx];

      if (idx < obj.seriesIndex) {
        beforeTotal += segment.data;
      }

      total += segment.data;
    }

    var beforePart = (beforeTotal / total * 100) * percentInRads;
    var chartStartAngle = currSegmentStart - beforePart;

    options.series.pie.startAngle = chartStartAngle;
    $.plot($("#pie-placeholder"), data, options);
    console.log(obj.series);
}

});
```

Comment: hey @t3mplar it is working fine..thanks alot.Also is there any way to make this spinning animation smooth? also remove the data coming on hover of the items and make that cursor as a pointer upon hover of the items? And place some data in the inner radius ( donut hole ) and increase the gap between the items ( please refer to the image i am attaching to the above question )

Comment: @k.p here's another example http://jsfiddle.net/c0hk96nd/ it's the most you can do with flot unfortunately