# how to animate smoothly the rotation of a donut chart item to the bottom position( 270 degree or negative y-axis)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to achieve exactly this  [but using google charts library and with a smooth animation on click.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470834/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-the-mid-of-a-clicked-donut-element-and-the-ne) but using google charts library and with a smooth animation on click.

Here is the fiddle with a high-charts library of donut`

```
   google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
    data.addRows([
        ['A', roundNumber(11 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['B', roundNumber(2 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['C', roundNumber(2 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['D', roundNumber(2 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['E', roundNumber(7 * Math.random(), 2)]
        ]);
    var options = {
        width: 450,
        height: 300,
        colors: ['#ECD078','#ccc','#C02942','#542437','#53777A'],
        legend: {position:'none'},
        pieHole: 0.4,
        animation: {duration:80600,easing:'in'}
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);    
    function selectHandler(){
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
    data.addRows([
        ['A', roundNumber(111 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['B', roundNumber(21 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['C', roundNumber(22 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['D', roundNumber(23 * Math.random(), 2)],
        ['E', roundNumber(74 * Math.random(), 2)]
        ]);
        chart.draw(data, options);

    }
}
```

Comment: It is not Highcharts library

Comment: Yeah my bad..but can this achieved using highcharts ? @morganfree

Comment: You can try to update pie's startAngle - http://jsfiddle.net/0xL048um/3/